# How Can I Achieve a Singleton Subscription To router.events in Angular 9

Tags: angular, observable

```
    constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller
  ) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll))
      .subscribe((e) => {
        if (e.position) {
          console.log("// position navigation", e.position);
          this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
        } else if (e.anchor) {
          console.log("// anchor navigation", e.anchor);
          this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
        } else {
          console.log("// forward navigation");
        }
      });
  }
```

I have the code above (or equivalent) in an angular 9 component. When I move back and forth in the application, coming to the component again and again using forward and back navigation, I notice that the subscriptions to `router.events` keep mounting up... Yet there is no way to unsubscribe from the `router.events` for instance inside of ngOnDestroy... How can I achieve a singleton event subscription in this case?

Comment: Why exactly can't you clean up in `ngOnDestroy` (either with `unsubscribe`, or using `takeUntil` and a subject that emits in `ngOnDestroy`)?

Comment: @mbojko router.events doesn't have unsubscribe method

Comment: You don't unsubscribe a stream, you unsubscribe a subscription. _Every_ subscription has the `unsubscribe` method, doesn't matter what the source was. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html

Answer (score 1):

An Observable doesn't have an `unsubscribe` method but a `Subscription does`. When you call `.subscribe` on an Observable, it returns a `Subscription` object. This is what we use to unsubscribe from our Observables.

```
export class YourComponent implements OnDestroy {
    routerSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller
  ) {
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll))
      .subscribe((e) => {
        if (e.position) {
          console.log("// position navigation", e.position);
          this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
        } else if (e.anchor) {
          console.log("// anchor navigation", e.anchor);
          this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
        } else {
          console.log("// forward navigation");
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.routerSubscription) {
      this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.routerSubscription = undefined; // just in case. If this.routerSubscription is undefined, calling .unsubscribe() on it will throw an error and halt your component
    }

  }
}
```

Above is a simple example. Hope this helps